# kivy: How to pass arguments to a Widget Class

Tags: python, class, kivy, arguments

I want to create a UI passing an argument to a part of my interface.
I know that, in this example, I could just put the label text as a variable and change it from the code, but this is a very simplyfied example. What i really need is to delete and recreate an object (a layout widget) inside my main Screen using different arguments each time.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyBox(Boxlayout):
    def __init__(self, text, **kwargs):
        super(MyBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = text
        lbl = Label(text=self.text)
        btn = Button(text=f'Modify "{self.text}" label')
        self.add_widget(lbl)
        self.add_widget(btn)
            
class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    text1 = 'Hello Kivy'
    text2 = 'Goodbye Kivy'
    # I want this text to be passed to the MyBox object

class MainApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

And the kv file:

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Title'
    Label:
        text: 'Subtitle'
    MyBox:
    Label:
        text: 'Bottom text'
    Button:
        text: 'Exit'

<MyBox>:
```

Later (I haven't done it yet) i would like to change the middle section deleting that MyBox object and creating it back again passing another argument.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean : `MyBox` by '*delete and recreate an object (a layout widget)*' ? If that's the case and if you want to add `MyBox` in `MainWidget` tentatively, you can use the method `add_widget(widget, specified index)` from `python`. In that case, you can also access and implement the 'text's (may be better with `StringProperty`) in `MyBox` by its `on_parent` method.

Comment: It worked! I could instantiate my Object and place it in the correct position by using the index. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass more arguments to a kivy class' `__init__`, you have to create a **Kivy attribute**, which is just replacing the normal attribute definition:

```py
class myClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attribute="hello world"
        #do stuff
```

into a Kivy attribute definition:

```py
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
class myClass(Widget):
#remember to always define Kivy properties before defining __init__
    attribute=StringProperty("hello world")
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #do stuff
```

This is how you let Kivy know to expect more arguments, and avoid the dreaded
`TypeError: Properties [property] passed to __init__ may not be existing property names. Valid properties are [list of kivy properties]`

I hope this helps someone looking for the answer, though it seems **you**'ve already found a different solution to your problem.

This knowledge came from debugging and reading this page: **https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html?highlight=properties**

In my case, passing properties like this was the way to go. Feel free to comment if you found another way to do it so this can be a more helpful search result.